# What's the difference between “reliable” and “dependable”?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, differences, synonyms

Do the adjectives “reliable” and “dependable” have the same exact meaning?
If not, what is the difference and when is best to use each of them?

Comment: We have a really great post about [how to ask meaning questions](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/writing-good-meaning-questions/). It applies equally to difference questions. Please edit your question to better fit those guidelines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OED gives the following definitions of reliable and dependable:

> Reliable—1. That may be relied on.
>
> 1a. Of a person, information, etc.: able to
>   be *trusted*; in which reliance or
>   confidence may be placed; *trustworthy*,
>   safe, sure.
>
> 1b. orig. U.S. Of a product, service, etc.: consistently good in
>   quality or performance; **dependable**.
>
> Dependable—That may be depended on; *trustworthy*, **reliable**.

Both definitions list the other word in their definitions, with no special qualifiers attached. In addition, both words use the word *trustworthy*, also without qualifiers. Therefore, it is safe to say that the two are synonyms and may be equally used.

Comment: Additionally, the first line is a circular definition.

Answer (score 10):

Here is the discussion of *reliable* and *dependable* in *Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1942):

> A person or thing is **reliable** when one can count on him or it not to fail in doing what he or it is expected to do competently (as, she is a very *reliable* servant; one of the most *reliable* of our employees; a *reliable* washing machine), or to give or tell the exact truth (as, a *reliable* work of reference; *reliable* testimony. A person or thing is **dependable** to whom (or which) one can go in full confidence that one will get the support or assistance required in time of need or in an emergency; as, to ask a friend to recommend a *dependable* physician; he is the most *dependable* of our friends; a *dependable* source of information. *Dependable* is also used merely as a descriptive term  implying a character that admits nothing that is incalculable, or that is the antithesis of that which is fickle, capricious, or the like. "Laura wasn't pretty, but ... healthy-looking and *dependable*" (*M. Austin*).

Here is the corresponding discussion in James Fernald, *Funk & Wagnalls Handbook of of Synonyms, Antonyms & Prepositions*, revised edition (1947):

> *Reliable* denotes the possession of such qualities as are needed for safe reliance; as a *reliable* pledge, *reliable* information. A man is said to be *reliable* with reference not only to moral qualities, but to judgment, knowledge, habit, or perhaps pecuniary ability. ... A *dependable* person or thing can be relied on to help whenever a need arises[.]

Interestingly, the first edition of Fernald's dictionary (1896) opens with the comment that "The word *reliable* has been sharply challenged, but seems to have established its place in the language." Fernald then goes on to show why the criticism "on the ground that the suffix -able can not properly be added to an intransitive verb" is baseless, and then compares *reliable* to *trustworthy* and *trusty*—but not to *dependable*, which it doesn't cover at all.

Finally, here is the discussion of the two terms in S.I. Hayakawa, *Choose the Right Word* (1968):

> **Reliable** suggests competence and consistency: A *reliable* judge is one who has a record of sound opinions. A *reliable* person can be counted on to do what he has promised or been told to do: a *reliable* baby sitter.When applied to things, *reliable* means adequate, serviceable, or true; a reference book, for example, might be called *reliable* if the information it presents is accurate. **Dependable** is akin to *reliable*, but is a little more subjective; *reliable* is often used of relationships based on service  between superiors and inferiors, whereas *dependable* more often suggests an attitude of personal allegiance rather than one of honesty or scrupulosity in the performance of a duty. One goes to a *dependable* person confident of receiving loyalty, support, or aid: a *dependable* ally. When applied to things, *dependable* suggests stability and consistency of performance: a *dependable* drug.

As with all books that attempt to delineate fine distinctions between words that have similar meanings, the ones I cite here inhabit a gray zone where distinguishing between actual differences in preponderant informed usage (on the one hand) and the authors' desire to establish differences that may not be widely observed in practice (on the other) can be difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously "reliable" means "can be relied upon" and "dependable" means "can be depended upon", but both my Webster's and etymological dictionary give near-identical usages, even using the other as synonyms.

Google [Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reliable%2C+dependable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows "reliable" as far more common than "dependable".

Answer (score 0):

*Reliable* and *dependable* are interchangeable when they refer to things (i.e. a clock), or to oneself vis-a-vis someone else. However, there is a nuance when the terms apply to someone else vis-a-vis oneself. In this case *reliable* implies a decision to commit oneself to another and to acept the consequences in the event of failure. With *dependable*, the commitment is not a free choice. (Source: *The Heritage Illustrated Dictionary of the English Language, International Edition, McGraw Hill*.)

Comment: "With *dependable*, the commitment is not a free choice": Really? That distinction is made in your dictionary?