# Difference in usage between "Dependent" and "Reliant"

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, connotation

Based on the comments on a question on another SE site, I'm trying to define the difference between something being "Dependent upon something" and being "reliant upon something".

The sentence in question was: "It is well know that if you feed animals that they become dependent."  The comments devolved into a debate over whether the animals were *dependent* on the provided food, or whether they were *reliant* on it.

One contention was that the former is a subset of the latter - if you rely on something you can find other sources, but if you depend on it, you can't.  The other was that they were entirely equivalent, which the dictionary seems to support.

Is there a correct usage?  Are there implied differences that a straight dictionary lookup doesn't provide?

**Edit:** Answers based on the verb forms (*depends* and *relies*) would be fine, if they transfer over to these adjectives, but not ones based on the positive adjective form (*dependable* and *reliable*).

Comment: Please note: this is *not* a duplicate of [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68769/whats-the-difference-between-reliant-relying-and-dependent), which addresses the code definition of dependence, or [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11557/whats-the-difference-between-reliable-and-dependable?rq=1) which asks about the positive adjectives.  If there's another related question, I didn't see it when I checked.

Comment: *Reliant* is irrelevant to the context, *dependent* it is. Better than a detailed answer, a careful survey of usage can help see why.

Comment: The question is not what is right in this case, but what is the difference in the words.  Are they exact synonyms or is there a subtle context.  The actual statement of contention was Are people dependant on food stamps or merely reliant and is there a difference in the wording.  That was not used here to try and keep the political debate out of this question.

Answer (score 2):

The difference here is one indicates a choice where the other indicates absence of choices.

> For instance a small African village is dependent on the rains to
>   refill its wells.  If the rains do not come there is no other way to
>   fill the well.  The village relies on the well to provide water.  If
>   the rains do not come then they will be forced to trek many miles on
>   foot to the next nearest water source.

While it would not sound wrong to use depends on the well here it would be inaccurate. The village has other has options for water supply.

Also dependence infers reliance, but reliance does not infer dependence.

Answer (score 0):

The idea that there's some semantic distinction based on the availability of alternatives is completely spurious. At that level, *in OP's context* the words are effectively synonymous.

But idiomatically, the fact is that *reliant* would probably never be used in that exact context. It's not used much in *any* context, for that matter. Consider...

[image]

Offhand I can't think of any context where *reliant* would actually be the "preferred" term. But *dependent* is really the only acceptable option where it's just an "unqualified adjective" (i.e. - *"These animals are dependent"*, as opposed to *"These animals are reliant **on human intervention**"*).

My advice would be to forget the word *reliant* completely. You can probably use the verb forms *depend/rely* interchangeably in all relevant contexts, but only *dependent* can be ***relied*** upon in all adjectival contexts (but that's one case where I personally would prefer the verb form of *to rely!* :)

Comment: -1 Sorry, FF. *Reliant* is used in some contexts and it is possible even in the OP's context with an entirely different implication. And I want to say nGrams is not much help at all here, because the meaning with which *reliant* is used, esp., in scientific literature, makes it a much rarer word than *dependent*.

Comment: I'd be willing to accept an answer partially based on the verb forms too, if you want to account for those.

Comment: @Kris: Well, I've got two downvotes already, so presumably at least one other user knows what you're getting at, and agrees. But OED tells me that *reliant = a person who relies on someone; a dependent* is both obsolete ***and*** rare. And all seven of their examples for the still-current "adjectival" sense are "qualified" (for example, *reliant **upon** something*). OED makes no mention of any special "scientific" meaning, so I really think the onus is on you to expand on your position.

Comment: @Bobson: My NGram above shows that *he is reliant* is much less common that *he is dependent*, but [this one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+depends+on%2Che+depends+upon%2Che+relies+on%2Che+relies+upon&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20depends%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20depends%20upon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20relies%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20relies%20upon%3B%2Cc0) shows that *as a verb*, "rely" is in fact significantly more common.

Comment: I don't know how to do it in NGrams, but I know it's possible to exclude all instance where the adjective (*dependent* or *reliant*) is NOT followed by either *on* or *upon*. I believe if that were done, even the relatively small number of instances of *reliant* in my first chart would all disappear. I don't think I've ever heard bare *reliant* used to describe anyone or anything, but I can't rule out the possibility there's some rare specialised scientific context I'm not familiar with. We'll have to wait and see if Kris responds.

Comment: ...I did find this in [Philip K Dick's *Deus Irae*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_lD0gJ8yOgMC&pg=PA102&dq=%22he+is+reliant+how+long%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KESrUtzQH6Ha4AS_hIHIDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22he%20is%20reliant%20how%20long%22&f=false) - *"What does this dog eat?" "Anything. He is reliant."* But I must say that looks like it should have been ***self-reliant***.

Comment: @Fumblefingers - The question is what is the difference in the words not so much what is the right word to use in this case.  I think your last paragraph starts to move toward that answer.

Answer (score -2):

**The words are synonymous.**

> For instance a small African village relies on the rains to refill its wells. If the rains do not come there is no other way to fill the well. The village depends on the well to provide water. If the rains do not come then they will be forced to trek many miles on foot to the next nearest water source.

Dependence infers reliance, and reliance infers dependence.

Comment: This is not grammatically incorrect but it is inaccurate

Comment: @Chad, does the village choose to rely on the rain to refill their well, or do they have no other option? (Could they trek many miles on foot to obtain water and throw that water in the well?)

Comment: No because when the water table drops putting that water into the well will just be absorbed into the same layer that provides them with water when they do have the rains.

Comment: @Chad, your understanding of physics is inconceivable. What if the villagers brought back trillions upon trillions of water droplets (like the rain), then would they refill their well?

Comment: No ***a village*** could not transport enough water by hand from  to fill the watertable of Central Africa.  You should probably commit here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36296/geoscience so that you can learn why.

Comment: @Chad, my question was more theoretical than practical. Villiagers depositing rain in their well is essentially the same thing as rain depositing it on the land and settling into the water table, it is just a matter of scale (water is incompressible, so any droplet raises the well's level). If you prefer a more practical version, could an African village build a series of desalinization plants and water pumps to pump water from the ocean to their well? Would that refill the well?

Comment: But when the water table falls below the level of the well then there is no water for the villages.  This is something that actually happens. That is why I chose this for my answer which you then decided to try to corrupt and are now failing. In your example though they would no longer be dependant or reliant on the rains since they have desalization plants and piping to provide them with fresh water that is better than the stuff they get from the well.